# How can I insert some XAML snippet in to my window as child element?

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-snippets

I have some **XAML** (as string) like this:

```
 <Grid>
        <TextBlock>some text</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

And I want to insert it into my window without generating it in code behind:

```
 <Window  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="BookOnTheFly.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
 <insert xaml snippet here>
    </Grid>
</window>
```

I mean something like jQuery append..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a resource.  A resource is a snippet of XAML code that conforms to certain requirements that is put in a resource dictionary.  Resources can be defined at the application, window or on any framework element.  Once defined, it can be referenced in various ways.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsldesigner/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight/

**Edit:**

Put my desired XAML code in resource ditionary :

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="insertion">
        <!-- XAML here -->
    </DataTemplate>
```

and use it as data in Content Control:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource insertion}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

In code you would add the element to the `Children` of the Grid. Something like this

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
     <!-- Where your code will be inserted -->
</Grid> 

<Grid Name="toBeInserted">
    <TextBlock>some Text</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
grid.Children.Add(toBeInserted);
```

**Note:**
You will get an exception if the thing you're adding is already the child of another element. You must remove it from that element first before adding it to the new one.

```
oldContainer.Children.Remove(toBeInserted);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I mean from string.